# Problem with export to Oracle using JDBC PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I've discovered a very strange problem using JDBC.

I have to export data from some no-SQL database (it's HCL by the way) to Oracle using java JDBC.
I did it many times before.
Now something very strange happens.

```
String query = "insert into INT.IMMUNITY_INT(APPID, APPDT, TAB_N, FIO, IMMUNITYDT, REASON, UPDATED) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";  
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);  
...  
preparedStatement.setString(1, "2022-000122");  
...  
updatedCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Program hangs!
No errors. It just hangs.

But if i make:

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "2022 000122");  
'or  
preparedStatement.setString(1, "2022_000122");  
'or  
preparedStatement.setString(1, "№2022-000122");
```

it works fine!

The cloumn in Oracle table has type: VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)

A very mistical error happens when I try setString with data that only contains numbers and "-".

Why doesn't it work with numbers?

P.S.
Turns out it works fine too:
preparedStatement.setString(1, "2023-000122");

Problem only occurs with number "2022-000122".
Maybe it's uncommited trunsaction? I've restarted server which executes java-agent (HCL), but it didn't help.

Comment: The hang sounds as if it is waiting for something, which would either be a lock or possibly free space (less likely). Are there any unique constraints or unique indexes on this table that could play a role? Any foreign keys on the column you are updated? And are you alone working with one thread, or are there multiple threads or users updating the same tables?

Comment: I'm alone working with that thread. There are no other users working with that table. And when I change "preparedStatement.setString(1, "2022-000122");" to "preparedStatement.setString(1, "2022_000122");" - it works fine.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to answer the question.  For one thing, we don't know if `query` contains an `INSERT` or other DDL statement, or perhaps a call to a stored procedure. There could also be a trigger on the table that is making a lot of changes to another table: we have no ideas on volumes of data here. An uncommitted transaction in another session could cause problems too.

Comment: I've added query info. I've made some more test. Problem only occurs with number "2022-000122". Maybe it's uncommitted trunsaction. How can I check this? I'm sure there is no triggers or connections to other tables. It's test environment.

Comment: What happens if you use "9999-999999" or some other combination that does not exist in the table and is less likely for a competing insert? As for uncommitted transactions, ask your DBA to check if there is an active session that has a lock on the table and kill it. Or if it is your box, simply restart it and kill all sessions the hard way.

Comment: As I mentioned before if I try to insert a new combination that does not exist in the table - it works. preparedStatement.setString(1, "9999-999999"); - works too. I'll ask DBA about locks tomorrow. It's not my box.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.
It was lock.
Maybe connection was not closed in Java-agent.